# jQuery .change() function heavily delayed with number-input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an issue with the .change() function in JQuery in combination with an input of the type "number".
Quick and dirty mockup that gets the point across:
JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vtuk69bj/

```
$('#testInput').change(function(){
$('#testDiv').html($('#testInput').val());
})
```

As you can see if you use the arrows inside the input to increase/decrease numbers quickly (or even not so quickly), the function is incredibly delayed in some cases.

I know I could use stuff like keyup or click, but that wouldn't cover both the option to increase/decrease with arrows or straight up input a number yourself. Is there some way to cover all my bases without having 2-3+ different functions?

Comment: Change happens when the focus is lost from the input field.  So long as you have focus, and are hitting up and down, it will not happen until focus is lost.

Comment: Change your binding to use the 'input' event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input` event fires any time the value of the input changes.

```js
$('#testInput').on('input', function() {
  $('#testDiv').html(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="testInput" type="number" min="1" max="999">
<div id="testDiv">
  1
</div>
```